# Is there an extensive source where one can look up artworks of Magic: The Gathering expansions?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm interested in looking up some of the artworks found on Magic: The Gathering cards. Is there a website where card art is featured, preferably in higher definition than on the various card search engines? I am highly interested in artworks from the *Coldsnap* expansion, where you seem to find little in terms of artworks.

Answer (score 2):

Wizards releases some of the card arts in larger size in their [wallpaper gallery](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/media/wallpapers), however I didn't see any Coldsnap art in there.

Other than that I would suggest seeing if the artist for the card you are looking for has their own website, since the artists do retain some right to their artwork. For example [John Avon](http://www.johnavon.com/) and [Steve Arglye](http://www.steveargyle.com/) are both artists for Magic that have some of the artwork they've done at higher resolutions.

Comment: I already tried scouring the artist's websites. Problem is: a lot of classic Magic artists don't publish a lot of their works online (like Brian Snoddy, for example). This is why I am looking for an extensive collection. But thanks for mentioning the wallpaper gallery, did not know about that, and the pictures are high-res.

Comment: @JosephDoob it looks like Brian has a website, it doesn't look like there is any Magic art on there, but it does have a Contact Form where you could probably ask him.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a google search brings up http://www.artofmtg.com and it does look like they have a Coldsnap gallery.  It doesn't tend to have all card images, but it does have a good number.

Comment: I can see only 2 Coldsnap artworks there, and older sets are almost non-represented. Still, a good ressource for newer sets.